# "Equalise" one data set into another data set using neural network

Tags: matlab, neural-network, regression, calibration, non-linear-regression

I have two non-linear curves as shown below: [image: 1]

The Blue solid curve is the current sensor data I am getting with respect to time. The red dashed function is the data from the gold standard. Its more of a calibration/regression problem. I want to "equalise" the blue curve to the red one as shown below: [image: 2]

I have been reading about ANN lately. But I need help regarding how to move forward in solving it. I am using MATLAB.

Comment: but did you get some others parameters that could help you to calibrate your sensor ? Because here for the sames blue line's values you have some totally differents red line's values

Comment: Let's see, this graph , as you see is a gait movement (Body weight distrubution as you walk) . So I have the time duration of the step and weight of the person that is common.